# ios interface builder layout oddity

Tags: ios, layout

I'm using XCode+IB to layout a pretty simple view.  There is a standard NavigationController navigation bar at the top.  Inside the main View is another View which contains a Label, and then a table below that takes up the rest of the screen.  I put the label in this container view because I want that area below the navigation bar to have a background color (gray).

The problem is that even though the main View starts just below the navigationBar, the label's container view is exists underneath the navigation bar.  Sort of.  You see, the label appears below the nav bar, but the gray background is somehow under the navigation bar.  If I set the height of the label's view to be 75px, it just starts to appear below the navigation bar. (22+44 for statusbar and navigation bar)

Auto-layout is disabled.

So why is the View container starting below the navigation bar for the background? (but not its internal label?)

Since IOS7, I use this in the ViewController so that the content starts below the navigation bar, instead of underneath it.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]){
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```

I realize alternatively I can set the main view's background or make the label especially large perhaps and give it a background, but I'd like to see why this isn't working first.

EDIT:
I added a feature to this View where the main view will shift upwards 125px when the keyboard is opened for some UITextFields.  Interestingly, the entire view shifted except for the Label's View container.  That view remained in place while it's parent view shifted up and back.  The label itself shifted up and down however.  So once again, the middle View seems linked to the Window, and not the actual main View...

[image: IB]

[image]

Comment: Regarding your actual problem, it's hard to understand specifically what you are referring to. Sounds like you've created a UIView and positioned it so that it's y-coord is just below the nav bar and that the UILabel, that you've placed within the UIView is somehow presenting out of bounds (i.e. below) of the UIView (which doesn't make sense)

Comment: The label's container View is positioned at 0,0... which should place it just below the navigation bar since UIRectEdgeNone is set.  The label is inside this container view, and the label correctly appears in position on the overall Screen.  However, the container view's background is set to gray, it it isn't visible.  It is underneath the nav bar apparently, not respecting the UIEdgeRectNone logic?  That the label and it's container view are disjointed like this, does not make sense either.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Adjust Scroll view Insets on!

Go to your view controller, and it is under the Attributes Inspector

Comment: I'm not using storyboards, but if I set it programmatically to NO, it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a header cell if you just want to be able to post a message or instructions just below the nav bar. You can then avoid the extra UIView thing. The header cell will not scroll with the table view if that is your concern and it will position just below nav and above the rest of the table cells. Here is a simplified example that uses a custom header cell setting the background color. You can also drop UILabels, etc. into the cell via IB if you choose.

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{  
    MyCustomHeaderCell *headerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomHeaderCell"];
    headerCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    return headerCell;
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion.  The one thing I don't like about section headers is that they bounce down when you pull the table down too far.  And alternatively disabling bounce on the table feels unnatural.

Comment: It shouldn't bounce. It should be stationary relative to your non-header table cells (which will bounce)